# Is it Possible to Enable and disable CORS dynamically in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a api method, where it will give some result based on that result I have to conclude whether i have to send the response to the request or not. For that i need to enable CORS at runtime in c#. For each request it should enable or disable CORS . Is this scenario possible in c#?

Comment: Can you clarify the situation? Do you want to send CORS headers based on the request origin? Or perhaps you just want to send a HTTP 403 (Forbidden) response?

Comment: [Custom Cors Policy Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#custom-cors-policy-providers)

Comment: @Stijn thanks for your interest. I need to send CORS headers based on the request origin.

Comment: Then you can either use the `origins` parameter of the `EnableCorsAttribute`, or do as Patrick answered and implement a custom provider.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be something that needs more work then just some standard configuration using `EnableCors` attributes as you would normally do.

I would advize to implement a custom CORS policy provider or factory, so you can filter requests on a one-by-one basis. (You just return another policy on the HTTP request.)

More information on implementing such provider or factory can be found in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#custom-cors-policy-providers).